# Why there is an error showing when I try to load the slider in the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have save the code in slider.js. But when in the browser the slider is not working. It is showing the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined.

But I'm seeing the result of the `console.log("ready")` inside the `$(document).ready(...)` handler here:

Jquery code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  console.log('ready'); // <===== I'm seeing this
    $('.logo-carousel').slick({
      slidesToShow: 6,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 1000,
      arrows: true,
      dots: false,
      pauseOnHover: false,
      responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 768,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 4
        }
      }, {
        breakpoint: 520,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2
        }
      }]
    });
});
```

Error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at Slider.js:1:3
```

Comment: No! Because the document.ready function is working and it also print 'ready' in console.But it is still throwing the error $ is not defined.

Comment: Are you sure the jquery library is loaded?

Comment: If it is not loaded then how ready is printing in console?

Comment: @Sarkar - Is the code above wrapped in anything, or is it at global scope? And are you doing this on Wordpress?

Comment: does this solve your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined

Comment: In the console works because Google Chrome aliases `document.querySelector` as `$` :) but you are missing JQuery

Comment: @CristianTraìna - The OP says they're seeing the result of the `console.log("ready")` in the `$(document).ready(...)` function.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Right! So I suppose that OP opened the console in a webpage where JQuery was loaded

Comment: @CristianTraìna - It's code in the script, not something they typed in the console.

Comment: In a previous edit, OP had said that `in console "ready" is showing`, so I was attempting to explain why the behaviour was different :)

Comment: @CristianTraìna - I think they were referring to that line of code. :-) English is clearly not their first language.

Comment: it's saying the $ is undefined in your slider.js file so did you include that file before you included the jquery file?  Please can you show the code where you include your scripts

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the code you've shown is at global scope, I can only think of three possibilities:

1. You've included `Sliders.js` before including jQuery and the code you've shown in the question.
2. You're using an `iframe` and loading `Slider.js` into it, but jQuery isn't loaded in that `iframe`; your code is in the main document (or a different `iframe`) where jQuery *is* loaded, so it has `$` but the `iframe` with `Slider.js` doesn't. Remember an `iframe` is a completely different window from the window containing it. If you want to use jQuery in that `iframe`, you have to load it in that `iframe`.
3. (This seems unlikely) Code running **after** your code is doing this:

   ```
   $.noConflict(); // This part is optional but likely to be there
   delete $;       // This causes the specific error you're seeing
   ```

#1 is the most likely scenario, followed by #2; #3 is possible but unlikely.

I won't do an example of #2 because it's awkward with Stack Snippets, but here's an example of #1:

```html
<script><!-- This is Slider.js -->
$(document).on("click", ".slider", function() {
    // ...
});
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(() => {
    console.log("ready");
});
</script>
```

And here's an example of #3:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(() => {
    console.log("ready1");
});
</script>
<script>
$.noConflict(); // This is optional but likely to be there
delete $;       // This causes the specific error you're seeing
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(() => {
    console.log("ready2");
});
</script>
```

Notice we see `ready1` but get an error instead of seeing `ready2`.

If the code following your code **only** did `$.noConflict()`, you'd still get an error, but it would be a different one ("`$` is not a function). So something is actually removing the `$` property from the window object (via `delete $` or similar).

---

Side note: `$(document).ready(someFunction)` has been deprecated for some time now, [details here](https://api.jquery.com/ready/). Use `$(someFunction)` instead if you really need to ask jQuery to wait for the `DOMContentLoaded` event, or better yet use modules (they won't be run until the main parsing of the HTML is completely), or `defer` on your `script` tag, or put your `script` tag at the very end of the document. (But there are times you don't control the `script` tag, and in those situations `$(someFunction)` can be useful.)